# If a theory speaks of sets that cannot be forced to be parameter free definable, then does this entail a large cardinal property?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, large-cardinals, definability

If we say that an effectively generated first order theory $\sf T$ extends $\sf ZF$, such that every countable model of $\sf T$ doesn't have a class forcing extension that is pointwise definable. Would that just mean that $\sf T$ negates Choice? Or it does impart $\sf T$ proving some large cardinal property?

Comment: When you say "forcing extension", does this include class forcing? That is what is needed for the arguments of my paper with Linetsky and Reitz.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, yes, of course. I’ve edited it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $T$ is a theory which proves "there is no extension of the model to a model of $\sf ZFC$ without adding ordinals", then there is no extension of models of $T$ by a class forcing to a pointwise definable model, since pointwise definable models must satisfy $\sf ZFC$.

The obvious example is Gitik's model, but we also have the Morris model where no large cardinals are involved, and for every $\alpha$ there is a set $A_\alpha$ which is the countable union of countable sets and $\mathcal P(A_\alpha)$ surjects onto $\omega_\alpha$. If we extended the Morris model to a model of $\sf ZFC$, then all the $A_\alpha$ became countable and all their power sets became the same size and therefore proper classes.

Comment: In the first line "there is no extension of the model"  of what theory???

Comment: Of $T$?????????

Comment: You mean $T$ is an effectively generated FOL that extends ZFC and that proves that "there is no extension of a model of $T$ to a model of ZFC without adding ordinals". Isn't that inconsistent? Any model of $T$ extends to itself.

Comment: Your question is about theories extending ZF. I don't know how you conclude from "$T$ proves that there is no extension of the universe to a universe of ZFC without adding ordinals" to $T$ extends ZFC.

Comment: Ah! I see. So, T is an effectively generated FOL that extends ZF and that proves that "there is no extension of a model of T to a model of ZFC without adding ordinals". OK!

Comment: So, is this principle, a kind of a choice principle?

Comment: It implies there is a class generic extension satisfying AC, so in a sense, yes.